# Проблема в запросе в базу данных mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Приветствую, никак не могу правильно собрать запрос в базу данных.
Вот скрин таблиц и их связей:
[image: скрин таблиц и их связей] 
Нужно получить обязательный список из таблицы `events_global` с такими данными:

```
events_global.id, 
events_global.name,
COUNT(events.id) // это кол. мероприятий для каждого элемента из 
events_global,
COUNT(tickets.id) // количество билетов<br>
SUM(tickets.price) // сумма всех билетов принадлежащих каждому мероприятию из events_global
```

Вот так должна выглядеть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот [ссылка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76c34/1) на онлайн редактор mysql с залитой тестовой базой и недоразвитым кривым запросом

Проблема заключается в том, что в одном билете из табл. `tickets` может быть записано более одного мероприятия в табл. `ticket_events` и обращаясь начиная с `events_globals` проходя через `ticket_events` один и тот же билет затрагивается несколько раз и ломает все подсчеты. 
Буду очень благодарен всем, кто мне поможет.
 Уже долгое время мучаюсь над данной ситуацией

Comment: У вас же вроде все склейки последовательные. Выносите ticket_events из подзапроса как еще одну таблицу в join и берите `count(distinct e.id)` и `count(distinct te.id)`

Comment: @Mike, вот что получается http://prntscr.com/eus82r, каждое мероприятие посчитало по 2 раза, хотя должно по одном, и сумма должна быть 400

Comment: начал понимать ... у вас текстом сказано только что билет дает доступ на несколько мероприятий, но ни слова нет о том, что один билет может быть связан с одним мероприятием несколько раз. И такая структура БД кажется как минимум странной, в таблице ticket_events есть хоть что то уникальное кроме id, почему там две записи с одним и тем же событием и тем же билетом

Comment: Вот я при вашей текущей структуре хочу сделать простейшее "получить сумму price всех билетов проданных на мероприятие номер 1" и уже не могу это сделать, потому что единственный билет связан с мероприянием несколько раз, видимо вместо join c таблицей ticket_events придется делать   join c подзапросом `select distinct ticket_id, event_id from ticket_events` это сходу решит все проблемы, которые были заложены на стадии проектирования БД